# Org-mode: Setting EXPORT_FILE_NAME Externally

Tags: org-mode

I'm often working with org-mode 'externally' these days. I.e., I edit org-mode
files with Emacs, but then export the files using Makefiles to various other
formats by using rules such as:

```
%.tex : %.org
        $(EMACS) --batch --visit=$< --eval='(progn (setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)(org-latex-export-to-latex))'
%.html: %.org
        $(EMACS) --quick --visit=$< --eval='(progn (setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)(org-html-export-to-html)(kill-emacs))'
```

This works just fine, however at some point I wanted to 'extend' this slightly
with some special setting (omitted in this case), and consequently use a
different output path:

```
%.conf.html: %.org
        $(EMACS) --quick --visit=$< --eval='(progn (setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)(org-html-export-to-html)(kill-emacs))'
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to control the output path of the org-mode
export commands as by default they only use the buffer-file-name. The "closest"
options I have found is the setting `#+EXPORT_FILE_NAME: <file>` in the
header. However, I would like to change this **without** editing the file, i.e.,
"externally". Is this possible somehow?

(I suppose that creating a temporary file in the same directory **might** work,
but there may be subtle issues with that, something I'm hoping to avoid.)

Comment: I don't think you can "set" `EXPORT_FILE_NAME` externally (at least my cursory reading of the code has not uncovered such a method). The answer below is probably the best way to go, particularly since you are foregoing interactivity anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org-html-export-to-html` calls `org-export-to-file`

Manually calling `(org-export-to-file 'html "~/toto.html")` exports to the given file. So you can extend this to work with your makefile.

Comment: This works great! I only changed it slightly by using `(org-export-to-file (quote html) "$@")` to avoid quoting problems in the shell and to use the automatic Makefile variables